# generalizing unique factorization domains by allowing *infinite* factorizations

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

When we consider an unique factorization domain, we get a factorization with *finitely* many factors. Is it possible to generalize an *unique factorization domain* by still requiring an *unique factorization* but allowing for *infinitely many* factors?

Has this been studied, or is it impossible/not interesting anyway?

EDIT: An example: (I'm not sure yet, whether this is a valid example, but it perhaps helps to see what I'm aiming for.)

Consider the ring $R = \mathbb Z  \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \ldots$ of integer sequences with pointwise addition and multiplication, that is for $A=\{a_i\}_i, B=\{b_i\}_i \in R$ consider the addition $A+B = \{a_i+b_i\}_i$ and the multiplication $A\times B = \{a_i \cdot b_i\}_i$

If I'm correct, in this ring $p=(2,1,1,\ldots)$ is a prime, but so is $q = (2,0,0,\ldots)$. That means the factorization is *not unique*. But we can still factorize some elements into infinitely many prime factors: E.g. $r = (2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,\ldots)= (2,1,1,1\ldots) \times (1,2,1,1\ldots)^2 \times (1,1,2,1, \ldots)^3 \times \ldots$.

Again if I'm correct the prime numbers here have the form $(u_1, \ldots, u_k, p, u_{k+1}, \ldots )$ where $u_k \in \{0, \pm 1\}$ and $p \in \mathbb Z$ is prime.

We can almost make it unique by factorizing elmenets into primes of the form $(1,1, \ldots,1,p,1,\ldots)$, an unit $\{u_i\}_i$ with $u_i \in \{\pm1\}$ and a element $z=\{z_i\}$ where $z_i \in \{0,1\}$ for zeroing some entries. If we "ignore" the $z$ part, the factorization is unique.

Comment: What do you mean by "infinitely many factors"? Note that infinite products make no sense in general rings.

Comment: You'll have to consider some topological structure on the ring in order to discuss convergence of sequences at least.

Comment: I added an example. I was thinking of someting like an infinite dimensional module space with a multiplication.

Comment: Note that the product of two UFD's isn't a UFD, because the product of two non-trivial rings is never a domain. But see [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.637.5795&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for some material on "unique factorization rings", which in particular aren't required to be domains.